# Reset the iterator of CsvToBean from opencsv java package

Tags: java, opencsv

I am using `opencsv` package to read a `.csv` file.

I would like to read multiple times the same `.csv` file without re-opening the file and without re-creating the `Reader` object.

I am using the `reset()` method of the `Reader` object to reset the reading cursor at the start of the file.

Here is the code i am using :

```
reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path));

csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
            .withType(MyBean.class)
            .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
            .build();

it = csvToBean.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    MyBean csvData = it.next();

    // blabla ...
}


reader.reset();

// I do not want to recreate the csvToBean object, i've done it to investigate error
// I got the same result zhe i do not recreate the object
csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
            .withType(MyBean.class)
            .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
            .build();

it = csvToBean.iterator(); // <<<<<< FAILING HERE
```

Unfortunately, when i want to access the `Iterator` of the `CsvToBean<T>` object, i am encoutering the following error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error capturing CSV header!
>           at
>
> > com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.prepareToReadInput(CsvToBean.java:468)
> >             at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.iterator(CsvToBean.java:487)
> >             at com.myproject.test.main(test.java:37)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at
>
> > com.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.captureHeader(HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java:117)
> >     at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.prepareToReadInput(CsvToBean.java:466)
> >             ... 2 more

How to reset the reader of the reader properly with the `opencsv` package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `FileInputStream` passed to the `BufferedReader` object, and resetting the `FileInputStream` cursor to 0 solved my problem.

I was mixing `FileInputStream` that provides IO cursor manipulation with `BufferedReader` which provides tools on how much bytes will be load from the `FileInputStream`. My bad ...

```
fIn = new FileInputStream(Paths.get(path).toString());

reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));

csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
        .withType(MyBean.class)
        .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
        .build();

it = csvToBean.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    MyBean csvData = it.next();

    // blabla ...
}

fIn.getChannel().position(0);

reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));

csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
        .withType(MyBean.class)
        .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
        .build();

it = csvToBean.iterator(); // <<<<<< NOT FAILING HERE
```